# How to debug "Permisson denied" error when using Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, permissions, firefox-addon, stack-trace, firefox-addon-sdk

When testing and debugging an extension using Addon SDK 1.0 I'm sometimes noticing the following in the debug output window:

```
error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
Error: Permission denied to access object
```

Is there a any way to obtain more information? Some call stack info would be nice. Also it'd help to know to which "object" the access has been denied.

(I know I can put `console.debug()` calls before every statement but I'm looking for a more elegant way here)

Comment: Given that the traceback field is empty - Gecko itself doesn't seem to know that, the error apparently happened in some C++ code without any JavaScript on the stack. Which would indicate some async action, e.g. an `XMLHttpRequest` resulted in a redirect to a different host and prompted a `permission denied` error. Very hard to debug unfortunately, even `console.debug()` isn't much help with async actions.

Comment: Well it might indeed be a problem with `XMLHttpRequest` like you described. Doesn't solve the general question but might be enough to solve my specific problem. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried running the extension via `$ cfx run -v` ?

Comment: I just tried the `-v` option but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Wladimir pointed out, this is actually a deficiency in Gecko's error reporting. So to debug it without sprinkling `console.log()` all over, you'd have to either use a C++ level debugger or get the core deficiency identified and fixed. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435025 already tracks quite a few cases where the error messages could be improved.